# Can I setup an ssl certificate for AWS lightsail without the Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-lightsail

I have an instance built with ubuntu 16.04, it has 2 applications (no bitnami)

I setup the vhost pointing two differenst website and it works fine

but now that I'm trying to validate the ssl certificate I've been struggling

first, at all, I would like to know if **can set it up without using the Load Balancer ?**

in the AWS lightsail ssl documentation they only mention the load balancer but I also have a domain with an SSL certificate (I have my domains on namecheap )

I try certbot, looks like people setup without Load Balancer but using the steps from the bitnami documentation.. but I'm not using bitnami

config everything following the steps from https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-apache tested out on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ but I couldn't make it work, it only does the http redirect to https...but the https show the herror `This site can’t be reached`

I didn't setup any DNS I didn't see any turials using it just in the aws lightsail ssl

run `apachectl configtest`
no errors

I create a rule on my firewall for

```
http port 80

https port 443
```

what else can I look at?
I'm really confused and dont know what's the problem

Really appreciate

Comment: Same problem with nginx here

Comment: @ÁlvaroAgüero same issue, tried many things but didn't succeed, how you solved, can you share please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the most basic level, SSL is a function of the web server.  You can absolutely use SSL with lightsail without a load balancer.

I've used LetsEncrypt quite a lot with my lightsail instances.

certbot-auto automates the process quite nicely.

You need to verify that the certificates are setup in your apache configuration.

Take a look at https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/apache-configuration-example/2338 for an example.